# Model Location Timeline of Object

Tags: database-schema, database-design

I am looking to model the timeline of an object.  For example, a database model with airplanes and airports will have a class/table consisting airplanes arrival at airports and and the departure from these airports.  I am okay with the simple scenario of an airplane at an airport, the logic problems arise when changes are made.  Let's say that Airplane 1 wasn't at Airport 1 but was at Airport 2 and 3, this is where the model gets sticky.

I know that I am not the first person to have issues modeling a timeline of an object and was wondering if anyone could point me to some resources or give advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what kind of logic problems you're describing, or what use case you're aiming for, but here's a schema that sounds like it'd fit your example:

```
Airport
-------
AirportID INT
Airport VARCHAR

Airplane
--------
AirplaneID INT
Airplane VARCHAR

Arrival
--------
ArrivalID INT
AirplaneID INT
ArrivalTime SMALLDATETIME

Departure
---------
DepartureID INT
AirplaneID INT
DepartureTime SMALLDATETIME
```

OR instead of separate arrival and departure tables/classes, you could have an events class

```
EventTypes --Would have things like "Arrival", "Departure", "Delay", etc
----------
EventTypeID INT
EventType VARCHAR

Event
-----
EventID INT
EventTypeID INT
EventTime SMALLDATETIME
```

Comment: Right, that is the schema I am looking for.  But I am more concerned with the logic.  For example, lets say someone enters in a location timemline of a plane with the following properties.

Comment: Right, that is the schema I am looking for.  But I am more concerned with the logic.  For example, lets say someone enters in a location timemline of a plane with the following properties.  Munich:4:00-5:00PM.  Now lets say they add 2 new timeline objects Barcelona:4:20-4:45 , Paris:4:50-5:10.  So we see that the new timeline objects overlap with the Munich timeline object.  My question is how should this be handled, from a database and application perspective. Do I invalidate the Munich timeline object , or do I notify the user ?

Comment: Ohhh, ok, I think I see.  So for sake of clarification.  A plane leaves Boston at 12:10pm, and is set to arrive at Munich at 4:00pm (this sounds like a math problem lol).  Instead it has to re-route because of fuel or something to Paris?  Or maybe it hasn't even left yet, and it's instead going to go to Barcelona instead of Munich.  Is that close to the scenario(s) you're thinking of?

Comment: I would say you mark that timeline as invalidated for the planes it applies to, AND notify users.  I maintain a college class admin system with a somewhat similar use case.  I don't think you want to delete the invalidated timeframes, because you want something there triggering notifications to the users for as long as need be.  Ivalidate, notify, and add a new validated timeline.  When notifications no longer need to be sent, have some cleanup process sweep the old, invalidated entries out of the system unless they need to be saved for some reason.

Comment: @pheedbaq  Thanks for the help, I think I was really asking how do you handle it at the application level when the timeframe changes.  Do you erase the other timelines all together, or do you move their start and end dates so that they match up.

Comment: @FlexFiend: I would leave them at the app-level, yes, for the purpose of showing currently valid info to whoever is using the system (patrons? staff?).  Meanwhile, behind the scenes, the old timelines would still be there, triggering courtesy notifications to users who had records related to those timelines.  Unless you have some requirement to store a history of those timelines, it seems like you could set this up in different ways, so long as you don't leave people hanging when there's a change in a timeline.